# Is ECDSA signature strongly EUF-CMA?

Tags: signature, dsa, forgery

I read, [here](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/euf-cma-and-suf-cma/), that ECDSA signature is EUF-CMA but not SUF-CMA, aka sEUF-CMA (for *strong* existential unforgeability under adaptively chosen message attacks; see terminology [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/555)).

Specifically, the assertion is that given an ECDSA signature for a message, it is possible to transform it into a different signature that pass verification for that same message.

Is there such issue, and where exactly does it lie?

- mathematical definition
- standardized definition of signature in some edition of [ANS X9.62](https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/ascx9/ansix9621998) (paywalled), [SEC-1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf), or [FIPS 186](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=35)
- some implementations

Comment: The claim I have found (both on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm) and in [this peer-reviewed paper from 2002](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_7)) is that if $(r,s)$ is a valid signature, so is $(r,-s)$. Though I haven't fully understood the why of this (yet), though it is supposedly attributed to the ECDSA only using the x-coordinate of an intermediate point.

Comment: That [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_malleability) mentions an ASN.1 validation issue; several bullet points may apply!

Comment: …a bit late, but possible duplicate: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68188.  In particular, this comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/comparison-of-security-definitions-for-signatures/68194#comment151339_68194

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SEC1 v2.0 ([§4.1, pp. 43–47](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=49)), a *public key* is a point $Q \in E$, and a *signature* on a message $m$ is a pair of integers $(r, s)$ satisfying the signature equation (condensed from several steps):

\begin{equation*}
  r \stackrel?= f\bigl(x([H(m) s^{-1}]G + [r s^{-1}]Q)\bigr),
\end{equation*}

where $f\colon \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ projects the least nonnegative integer representative of an element of the coordinate field onto the scalar ring.  Here $G$ is the standard base point, and $H$ is a hash function mapping messages to scalars.

This equation is invariant under the transformation $\phi\colon (r, s) \mapsto (r, -s)$ because $(-s)^{-1} = -(s^{-1})$, $[-\alpha]P = -[\alpha]P$, $(-A) + (-B) = -(A + B)$, and $x(P) = x(-P)$.  It is also obviously invariant under the transformation $\psi\colon (r, s) \mapsto (r, s + n)$ because $s$ is used only as a scalar.

There are three additional requirements specified:

1. $r$ and $s$ must lie in the interval $[1, n - 1]$, where $n$ is the order of the group.
2. If $H$ returns invalid then the signature verification must fail.
3. $[H(m) s^{-1}]G + [r s^{-1}]Q$ must not be the point at infinity.

The only requirement relevant to strong unforgeability is (1), because it rules out the transformations $\phi$ and $\psi$ individually.  But it does not rule out, *e.g.*, $\psi \mathbin\circ \phi$, equivalent to $(r, s) \mapsto \bigl(r, (-s) \bmod n\bigr)$.

**Conceivably the signature scheme *could* require that $s$ be chosen to be ‘even’ like in ANSI X9.62 point compression, or be chosen to be in the lower half of the interval $[1, n - 1]$.  But such requirements are not imposed by verifiers, and so ECDSA cannot provide strong unforgeability.**

There are also other obvious ways that an implementation could fail to provide sEUF-CMA:

- The implementation could fail to check the intervals of $r$ and $s$.  (However, I don't know any that do.)
- The implementation could allow for many different encodings of a single integer.  For example, it could allow BER or DER encodings in some ASN.1 format—because the standard doesn't specify a *byte encoding* of integers; the signature scheme is really defined in terms of *integers*, a mistake avoided by EdDSA.

  This is the first source of [transaction malleability](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_malleability) that was [reported in Bitcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8392.msg122410#msg122410), prompting implementations to accept only the unique DER encodings of signatures and reject other encodings, before someone noticed the [negation vector too](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8392.msg1245898#msg1245898) a year and a half later.  (Exercise for the reader aching for a trip down a rabbit hole: Chronicle the saga of transaction malleability in MtGox and figure out what's up with the bankruptcy proceedings these days.)

Comment: Yeah, that's common (for the requirement to be there, not the actual occurrence of it of course, most if not all input data is significantly smaller than 2,091,752 terabytes - assuming SHA-256).