# What is the standard way to generate a unique non-reproducible ID?

Tags: signature, identity-based-encryption

Say that a manufacturer wants to label her products in such a way that a third party could verify that the manufacturer is the one that labeled the product, meaning it's not a counterfeit.

The manufacturer could have a serial number to each product, and have it signed with some signature scheme. However, this introduces some redundancy, as a verifier would have to use both the manufacture's public key *and* the serial number.

> Is there a different, more efficiently method create such labels?

Two cases are of special interest:

- The label should be publicly verifiable.
- The label should only be verifiable by an entity that share some secret information with the manufacturer (so perhaps encryption schemes are relevant).

Comment: Is it required that the third party doing the verification does **not** need to hold confidential data allowing whoever holds that data (including the third party) to forge a _Unique Non-Reproducible ID_? Is it required that a serial number (perhaps, sequential) is A) a subfield of the UNRID? B) recoverable by some other public process from UNRID? C) hidden but recoverable by some other process requiring a secret key? D) not needed?

Comment: @kelalaka: I'm not familiar with RFC 4122, but I do not see that its UUIDs are verifiable as thought by the question.

Comment: @fgrieu Not sure I understand the first question. I am interested in two cases: (1) The genuineness of the label should be publicly verifiable, and (2)  The genuineness of the label should be verifiable by an entity given some secret information by the manufacturer. 

A serial number _can_ be used if needed, but in my eyes it should be possible to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It is desired a Unique Non-Reproducible ID (UNRID) which genuineness is publicly verifiable.

I know no standard for that. But we can take as UNRID the signature of a public fixed message (e.g. empty), if the signature scheme is randomized and [EUF-CMA secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature_forgery#Existential_forgery_(existential_unforgeability,_EUF)). Verification simply checks the signature. If probability of collision among signatures is satisfactorily low, security follows from EUF-CMA.

The signature scheme could be RSASSA-PSS of [PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf"page=28), with the advantage of fast signature verification. But for modern security that requires 256 bytes (342 Base64 characters), which is a lot.

A more compact option is a slight variant of ECDSA, where a signature $(r,s)$ becomes the UNRID $(r,\min(s,n-s))$, which is presented as EUF-CMA secure [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75467/555), without proof but plausibly: EUF-CMA security of the signature scheme matters in Bitcoin, and was repaired with apparent success, in a manner equivalent to what's proposed. That would make the UNRID 64-byte (86 Base64 characters).

Using a signature scheme with message recovery, we can embed a serial number or other small ancillary information in the UNRID, without making it bigger. For RSA, ISO/IEC 9796-2 Scheme 2 would do (it's essentially RSASSA-PSS with message recovery). There are ECC-based randomized signature schemes with message recovery as compact as ECDSA, see [bibliography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40270/555).