# What is "one-time signature"

Tags: hash, hash-signature, one-time-signature

I'm studying the post-quantum cryptography (PQC).
While studying hash-based pqc, I read a thesis about Winternitz one-time signature scheme (W-OTS). What is the exact definition of "One-time Signature (OTS)"?
There is lots of papers and posts quote the word "OTS", but anybody didn't write the definition of OTS.

Answer (score 5):

Paraphrasing the short summary [there](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/446.pdf): A one-time signature (OTS) scheme is a digital signature scheme that can be used to sign one message per key pair, with no assurance of security if the key pair is reused to sign again.

The standard [(s)EUF-CMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68188/555) experiment defining signature security is modified by allowing adversaries to obtain a single signature.